# PL/SQL can't get multiple rows to update when a trigger fires

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-update

I'm trying to create a trigger to change one field when another is update. This is my current Trigger, it currently works IF I only update one row, but if I update multiple, it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

I'm using oracle by the way.

```
Create or replace trigger br_change
                after update on employees
                Declare 
                    cursor pls_work is
   select e.employeeID, e.departmentID, ep.billrate, jobrank,  salary  
   from employees e full join employeeproject ep on e.employeeID
    = ep.employeeID full join jobtypes jt on jt.jobname = e.title;
                empID number(3);
                dpID number(1);
                br number(4);
                jr number(1);
                s number(12);   
            BEGIN
                open pls_work;  
                fetch pls_work into empID, dpID, br, jr, s;
                update employeeproject set billrate = ((s/2000)+(jr*10)) where empID = employeeID;
                dbms_output.put_line('Updating billrate to match changes');
        END;
        /
```

Comment: “It doesn’t work” is not helpful. Tell us what actually happens - an error, wrong results? I imagine you end up with the wrong billrate value. It may be helpful to include sample data and current/expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If your UPDATE statement affects multiple rows the You need to add FOR EACH ROW